# Capturar Scroll pela barra de rolagem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Usuário preenche um formulário e clica em cadastrar. O sistema abre uma janela modal com o botão "concordo" desabilitado. 
Apenas ao rolar a barra de rolagem até o final é que o botão deve ser habilitado para cadastrar.
Pelo scroll do mouse ou touchpad tudo funciona mas ao clicar na barra e rolar até o final, o botão não é acionado.
É um código que roda dentro do WP.

Segue o código:

```
 <div id="popup" class="popup-content">
                    <div class="popup-inner" style="padding:20px;">
                      <p>
                        Por favor, solicitamos que leia o contrato até o final antes de clicar em aceitar, obrigado.
                      </p>
                      <div class="termos form--termos" id="termos" name="termos" style="height: 200px;overflow: scroll;background: #f2f2f2;margin-bottom: 10px;padding: 10px;">
                      bla bla bla bla bla
                      </div>

                      <a href="recusa" class="button button_large">
                        <span style="padding: 15px 30px;font-size: 110%;line-height: 110%;">Não aceito</span>
                      </a>

                      <button type="submit" class="button button_large form--btn-cadastro" >
                        <span class="button_label" style="padding: 15px 30px;font-size: 110%;line-height: 110%;">Concordo</span>
                      </button>
                      <hr class="no_line" style="margin: 0 auto 20px;">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

JS:

```
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(function() {
var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel";
    $j(".termos").live(mousewheelevt, function(e){


      if($j(this).scrollTop() + $j(this).innerHeight() >= $j(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
        $j('.form--btn-cadastro').attr('disabled', false).css('opacity', '1');
      }

      $j(".form--btn-cadastro").click(function() {
        $j("#form_cadastro").submit();
      });

    });
```

Como habilitar o botão através da rolagem da barra também?
Usando a versão 1.12.4 do Jquery.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce so precisa adicionar um `event handler` ao `onscroll` do elemento.

```
var readAll = false;
$elToBeRead.on("scroll", function() {

   if (readAll) return;

   readAll = this.scrollHeight - this.scrollTop === this.clientHeight;

   if (readAll) // ativar botao...
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ny6yct6k/